# How to remove or drop all rows after first occurrence of `NaN` from the entire DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking forward to remove/drop all rows after first occurrence of `NaN` based on any of dataFrame column.

I have created two sample DataFrames as illustrated Below, the first dataframe the `dtypes` are for initial two columns are `object` while the last one in `int`, while in the Second dataframe these are `float`, `obj` and `int`.

### First:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,'NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN'),"B": (1,2,3,'NaN',4,5,6,7,'NaN',"9","10"),"C": range(11)})
>>> df
      A    B   C
0     1    1   0
1     2    2   1
2     3    3   2
3     4  NaN   3
4     5    4   4
5     6    5   5
6     7    6   6
7   NaN    7   7
8   NaN  NaN   8
9   NaN    9   9
10  NaN   10  10
```

### Dtypes:

```
>>> df.dtypes
A    object
B    object
C     int64
dtype: object
```

While carrying out index based approach as follows based on a particular, it works Just fine as long as `dtype` is `obj` and `int` but i'm looking for dataFrame level action merely not limited to a column.

```
>>> df[:df[df['A'] == 'NaN'].index[0]]
   A    B  C
0  1    1  0
1  2    2  1
2  3    3  2
3  4  NaN  3
4  5    4  4
5  6    5  5
6  7    6  6

>>> df[:df[df['B'] == 'NaN'].index[0]]
   A  B  C
0  1  1  0
1  2  2  1
2  3  3  2
```

### Second:

Another interesting fact while creating DataFrame with `np.nan` where we get different `dtype`, then even index based approach failed for a single column operation s well.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan),"B": (1,2,3,np.nan,4,5,6,7,np.nan,"9","10"),"C": range(11)})
>>> df
      A    B   C
0   1.0    1   0
1   2.0    2   1
2   3.0    3   2
3   4.0  NaN   3
4   5.0    4   4
5   6.0    5   5
6   7.0    6   6
7   NaN    7   7
8   NaN  NaN   8
9   NaN    9   9
10  NaN   10  10
```

### dtypes:

```
>>> df.dtypes
A    float64
B     object
C      int64
dtype: object
```

### Error:

```
>>> df[:df[df['B'] == 'NaN'].index[0]]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
>>> df[:df[df['A'] == 'NaN'].index[0]]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Expected should be for the Second DataFrame:

```
>>> df
      A    B   C
0   1.0    1   0
1   2.0    2   1
2   3.0    3   2
```

So, i am looking a way around to check across the entire DataFrame regardless of `dtype` and drop all rows from the first occurrence of NaN in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
out=df.iloc[:df.isna().any(1).idxmax()]
```

OR

via `replace()` make your string 'NaN's to real 'NaN's then check for missing values and filter rows:

```
df=df.replace({'NaN':float('NaN'),'nan':float('NaN')})
out=df.iloc[:df.isna().any(1).idxmax()]
```

output of `out`:

```
    A       B   C
0   1.0     1   0
1   2.0     2   1
2   3.0     3   2
```

Comment: Anurag, thanks for the quick answer you spot on, i was doing `df.iloc[:df.isna().any().argmax()]` forgot to apply axis +1 already,  looking for other tricks before i do except it.

Comment: @KarnKumar glad it helped sir...happy coding **:)**

Answer (score 0):

Just for posterity ...

```
>>> df.iloc[:df.isna().any(1).argmax()]
     A  B  C
0  1.0  1  0
1  2.0  2  1
2  3.0  3  2

>>> df.iloc[:df.isnull().any(1).argmax()]
     A  B  C
0  1.0  1  0
1  2.0  2  1
2  3.0  3  2
```